# TreeView con Kendo UI y VueJs en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, nodejs, vue.js

Estimados no puedo desarrollar correctamente un treeview con Kendo UI y Vuejs en laravel.
Para desglozar el problema paso a describir lo que estoy utilizando.

Esto es lo que me devuelve la url del controlador (index) de laravel que luego voy a utilizar con kendoUi para crear el TreeView en base a datos json (me devuelve estos datos desde Mysql):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Problema es que se repiten todos los datos en el TreeView.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si utlizo la Url que me trae el ejemplo KendoUI funciona correctamente:

```
callback([{"EmployeeId":2,"FullName":"Andrew Fuller","HasEmployees":true,"ReportsTo":null}])
```

Paso a describir el codigo de:

KendoUI en Vuejs:

```
  <kendo-hierarchicaldatasource ref="remoteDataSourceComponent"
                                  :transport-read-url="'http://software.local/rubrosjson'"
                                  :transport-read-data-type="'json'"
                                  :schema-model-id="'EmployeeId'"
                                  :schema-model-has-children="'HasEmployees'">
    </kendo-hierarchicaldatasource>
    <kendo-treeview data-source-ref="remoteDataSourceComponent"
                    :data-text-field="'FullName'"
                    :checkboxes="true"
                    :drag-and-drop="true"
                    @change="onChange"
                    @check="onCheck"
                    @collapse="onCollapse"
                    @dataBound="onDataBound"
                    @drag="onDrag"
                    @dragStart="onDragStart"
                    @dragEnd="onDragEnd"
                    @drop="onDrop"
                    @expand="onExpand"
                    @navigate="onNavigate"
                    @select="onSelect">
    </kendo-treeview>
```

Laravel controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rubros;

use Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class RubrosJson extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       // return Rubros::all();
        $rubros = Rubros::all();
        $resultado = Response::json($rubros)->withCallback($request->input('callback'));;


            return $resultado;










    }
}
```